# ActiveAdmin doesn't set associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have to model Pizza and SizePrice

Pizaa.rb

```
class Pizza < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :size_price

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :size_price
end
```

SizePrice.rb

```
class SizePrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza
end
```

When I try to add SizePrice associated with Pizza it doesn't save id of associated Pizza element. I can select theme in SizePrice form in ActiveAdmin

Comment: Which version of rails is this? And which version of ActiveAdmin?

Comment: Rails 4, ActiveAdmin from github: 'gregbell/active_admin'

Comment: Have you setup necessary things for Strong Parameters? https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters

Comment: thx, I didn't set pizzas_id in permit_params in admin/size_price.rb.